# How to handle sign on with security restrictions in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, bdd, webautomation

I am a beginner in working with Cypress.

I am trying to build one test scenario for login.

1. I have this first url defined in cypress.json which is the page for signing in:
   "cozone_url": "https://idp-develop-devdb.staging.cozone.com/"
2. After successfully logging in, I am taken to the second page with URL: https://portal-develop-devdb.staging.cozone.com/ui/#/. In this page, I have one element which by clicking on it takes me to the actual application that I need to automate:

If I do not remove target attribute for the app element, the application opens correctly on a new child tab. I know that this is not handled with cypress so I tried to remove it:

```
 And ('I Click on Azets Invoice icon', ()=> {
 //this should open url https://invoice.test.azets.com/en
 cy.get("a[data-test-application-identifier='EFLOW_INVOICES_V2']").invoke('removeAttr','target').click() })
```

A new tab is not opened, but the https://invoice.test.azets.com/en is not loaded in the original tab and I have this error:
Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src

Also, when trying to go directly to the url with visit method I have this error:

*The new URL is considered a different origin because the following parts of the URL are different*

I know that this happens because of the security restrictions, that Cypress does not allow to change the domain within the same test, but how can I automate this scenario?

I login from url 1, then a page is opened where I have the link to my app and have to click on it and go to url2, which I am not allowed.

I tried to split this into 2 tests and use Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce() method, but I don't know which cookie name I should preserve for the second test.

Do you have any idea on how should I automate the scenario using Cypress?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off web security to remove CORS restrictions.

In `cypress.json` add

```js
{ 
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Ref: [Web Security](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it does not work for my case, I am still searching the solution in here.